# What is the difference between passing sbrk() an intptr_t vs int in C

Tags: c, sbrk

It seems to have no impact on the functionality of sbrk, but in sbrk()'s documentation it says that it requires an intptr_t parameter.

It works (or at least seems to work) when passing an int type as a parameter.

This is in regular C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the right header is included, you're not passing an `int` to `sbrk()`. The value you are passing is converted to `intptr_t` according to C promotion rules. These rules are terribly subtle so you should at least know they exist and avoid invoking them in corner cases.

As a consequence, do not expect something spectacular such as a crash, when you pass `sbrk` something that looks to you like an `int`, even if `intptr_t` is different from `int` on your platform, **as long as the header that provides `sbrk()`'s prototype is included**.

Comment: So when you pass sbrk() an 'int', it stores this value and passes an intptr_t with the location of the int?

Comment: @Bob No, promotion rules do not do this. Also `intptr_t` is an integer type, just not always the same as `int`.

Answer (score 6):

`intptr_t` changes size depending on the architecture. `int` may or may not change size depending on the architecture- that is, if you are on 64bit, then `intptr_t` MUST be 64bits, whereas `int` *may* be 32bits.

Comment: Isn't intptr_t a pointer though, not an actual value?  So in sbrk() there would be a dereference of intptr_t, whereas if you pass an int, there wouldn't be a dereference required.

Comment: @Bob `intptr_t` is an integer type, the smallest one that can contain all the bits of a pointer.

Comment: Oh that makes sense!  For some reason I thought it was a pointer.. Thanks for the clarification.  What is the significance of "all the bits of a pointer"?  Does that mean from machine to machine, the bits required for a pointer changes and so does the size of intptr_t?

Comment: @Bob Well, it changes "from platform to platform". The amd64 processors that most people have can work in 32-bit compatibility mode (32-bit pointers) or in 64-bit mode. Most OSes even allow 32-bit processes and 64-bit processes to coexist. But when compiling a C program you are either targeting one mode or the other.